# Getting a Value from a JsonArray using gson

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I have searched everywhere and cannot find out how to do this, I'm super stuck. I have NO experience with JSON files, so spoon feeding is appreciated along with an explanation.

I have this JSON text here for testing:

```
    {
      "id":"4566e69fc90748ee8d71d7ba5aa00d20",
      "properties":
                    [
                     {
                      "name":"textures",
                      "value":"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0ODI4ODAxNDMwNzYsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6IjQ1NjZlNjlmYzkwNzQ4ZWU4ZDcxZDdiYTVhYTAwZDIwIiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJUaGlua29mZGVhdGgiLCJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMTNlODFiOWUxOWFiMWVmMTdhOTBjMGFhNGUxMDg1ZmMxM2NkNDdjZWQ1YTdhMWE0OTI4MDNiMzU2MWU0YTE1YiJ9LCJDQVBFIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMjJiOWM1ZWE3NjNjODZmYzVjYWVhMzNkODJiMGZhNjVhN2MyMjhmZDMyMWJhNTQ3NjZlYTk1YTNkMGI5NzkzIn19fQ==",
                     },
                    ],
      "name":"Thinkofdeath",
    }
```

I currently have this:

```
    JsonElement playerProfile = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
    JsonObject jsonProfile = playerProfile.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonArray properties = jsonProfile.getAsJsonArray("properties");
```

Which returns
[

```
[
  {
    "name":"textures",
    "value":"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE0ODI4ODAxNDMwNzYsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6IjQ1NjZlNjlmYzkwNzQ4ZWU4ZDcxZDdiYTVhYTAwZDIwIiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJUaGlua29mZGVhdGgiLCJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMTNlODFiOWUxOWFiMWVmMTdhOTBjMGFhNGUxMDg1ZmMxM2NkNDdjZWQ1YTdhMWE0OTI4MDNiMzU2MWU0YTE1YiJ9LCJDQVBFIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvMjJiOWM1ZWE3NjNjODZmYzVjYWVhMzNkODJiMGZhNjVhN2MyMjhmZDMyMWJhNTQ3NjZlYTk1YTNkMGI5NzkzIn19fQ==",
  },
]
```

Of course. How do I get the "value" from this JsonArray? Note I'm using Google's API, Gson

Comment: as for me, usually i model the jsons to a pojo -- but you could always [get it as a JsonElement](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonArray.java#L182) and then [get as json object](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java#L86), finally [get("value")](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonObject.java#L169) to get `value` as (sadly) JsonElement.. it's pretty roundabout, but for sure, i'd suggest you to make pojo..

Comment: I appreciate your help, but like I said, I'm completely new to this JSON thing and kinda need a little spoon feeding :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get `values` using:

```
JsonObject propertiesJson = properties.get(0);
String value = propertiesJson.getString("value");
```

Comment: Aha! It works, just not it's not "getString" its "get("value").toString"

Comment: @SageM If you are using Json library than try to use its method for better convenience. get value as : propertiesJson.get("value").getAsString();

Comment: properties.get(0) is JsonElement, not JsonObject in Gson. I used this code. String name = properties.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();

Comment: in my case, I had to use jsonObject.get(object1) to get actual object first and then the .toString() method in Gson.fromJson();

Answer (score 0):

array is JsonArray object from com.google.gson library

```
for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject json = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    String value = json.get("key").getAsString();
}
```